# Changing color and font for cell in QgsLayoutItemTextTable object using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, layouts, table, color

I am in the process of creating, with PyQGIS, a PDF file.

First I set up the following objects:

- A value `project = QgsProject.instance()`
- A `layoutManager` object `"manager"`
- A `QgsPrintLayout` object `"layout"`

Then I created a `QgsLayoutItemTextTable` object `"table"`. Inside that table, I set up some columns and rows with custom values. I also set up a `QgsLayoutFrame` object `"frame"`:

```py
table.addFrame(frame)
```

Now I want to access one particular cell of the table and change the text color and font. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any straightforward way of modifying the style of an individual cell in a `QgsLayoutItemTextTable`. To be honest, I'm not sure that level of customisation is supported. There are methods such as [setContentTextFormat()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutTable.html#a62647a4fe8cf0066ef978da9a7893c0f) and [setCellStyle()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutTable.html#aa4fd328c4aef178b4a47fa2a4be48fde), but they are applied to either the entire table or a [cellStyleGroup](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutTable.html#aa3f5027a3c9747f6c647cf264b43fd51) e.g. odd or even rows/columns, first or last row/column etc.

So this is not exactly answering your original question, but I would strongly recommend you to use a [QgsLayoutItemManualTable](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItemManualTable.html) instead.

As far as I can see, the main difference is that the table contents is composed of [QgsTableCell](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsTableCell.html) objects which support full customisation such as background color, text format etc. at an individual cell level.

Here is a minimal example to create a manual table with some content and add it to a layout:

```py
tbl_items = [['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'],
            ['Item 4', 'Item 5', 'Item 6']]
            
tbl_contents = [[QgsTableCell(c) for c in r] for r in tbl_items]

l = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('Test Layout')
t = QgsLayoutItemManualTable.create(l)
l.addMultiFrame(t)
t.setTableContents(tbl_contents)

# Base class for frame items, which form a layout multiframe item.
frame = QgsLayoutFrame(l, t)
frame.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(100, 25), True)
t.addFrame(frame)

l.refresh()
```

Then you can modify an individual cell format like so:

```py
layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName('Test Layout')

frame = [f for f in layout.items() if isinstance(f, QgsLayoutFrame)][0]

# Access the table item
tbl = frame.multiFrame()

# Retrieve the table contents (nested lists)
tbl_contents = tbl.tableContents()

# Define the column & row indexes for your target cell
# *mind that the indexing starts from zero
col_idx = 1
row_idx = 1

# Retrieve the cell content
cell_content = tbl_contents[row_idx][col_idx].content()

# Create a new cell with the same content
new_cell = QgsTableCell(cell_content)

# Create a new text format object with font & color of your choice
txt_format = QgsTextFormat()
txt_format.setFont(QFont('Times'))
txt_format.setSize(12)
txt_format.setColor(QColor(0, 255, 0))

# Set text format to new cell
new_cell.setTextFormat(txt_format)

# Place the new cell in the table contents matrix
tbl_contents[row_idx][col_idx] = new_cell

# Set the modified contents to the table
tbl.setTableContents(tbl_contents)

# Refresh the layout
layout.refresh()
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently trying to implement it. Since my table is a QgsLayoutItemTextTable object, I got the error "AttributeError: 'QgsLayoutItemTextTable' object has no attribute 'tableContents'". But in QgsLayoutTable class, I found the method "getTableContents()". I believe it should do the same. However, I get the error "TypeError: getTableContents(self, contents: object): not enough arguments". It seems I am not calling it correctly. I wrote it that way : "tbl_contents = tbl.getTableContents()". Would you know the correct way to write this ?

Comment: @theonewhodidnotknow, I have updated my answer to suggest that you use a `QgsLayoutItemManualTable` instead with an example. P.s. `getTableContents()` does not do the same- it just fetches the contents, stores in a contents object and returns a boolean. You can call `contents()` on a `QgsLayoutItemTextTable` but it returns a matrix of plain strings, not `QgsTableCell`s which can individually customised.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great. I changed it a little to fit my code and managed to customize my table even more, adding several new parameters (header, color, font, wolumn width, line height...). Indeed, it is easier to use a QgsLayoutItemManualTable table.

Comment: @theonewhodidnotknow, that's great. You're welcome.